How to filter a Column (years) in a Child Table (Reports) When It Doesn't Exist in the Parent Table (Student) Using JPA Criteria API?
Want to select list of Student entities who are not associated with any Reports entries for a given schoolName and year.
But in the Student table, there is no years column, it must be checked against the child Reports table years column.
public List<Student> studentsInReports(String schoolName, String year) {
    try (Session session = sf.openSession()) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Student> cq = cb.createQuery(Student.class);
        
        Root<Student> root = cq.from(Student.class);
        Subquery<Integer> subquery = cq.subquery(Integer.class);
        
        Root<Reports> reportsRoot = subquery.from(Reports.class);

        subquery.select(reportsRoot.join("student").get("id"))
                .where(cb.and(cb.equal(reportsRoot.get("schoolName"), schoolName),
                       cb.equal(reportsRoot.get("years"), year)));
        
        cq.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get("schoolName"), schoolName),
                              cb.not(root.get("id").in(subquery)));
        
       return session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}

Even when a Student ID exists in the Reports table, the result list is not empty because the Student table does not have a years column.

You've overcomplicated this a bit. You want to query reports that have a 'years' column -  you've got that, right? Now you want to get the Students associated to those reports - this is a separate problem. How are these tables associated, and why are you trying to use a subquery for this if you want the actual student instances? Isn't this just "Select s from Report r join r.student s where r.schoolName = :schoolName and r.years = :years)"?

@Chris No I want to select student that does not associated with reports for given years and schoolname. So non associated student can be added to exam table.

What SQL is generated from your query attempt? Try using JPQL to describe what you want, and then work on criteria expressions - students not having a years column shouldn't be a problem, so don't using it in your problem definition. You want students that don't have reports for certain years, correct? "select  s from Student s where s.schoolName = :schoolName and not exists (select 1 from report r join r.student s1 on s1.id = s.id where  r.schoolName = :schoolName and r.years = :years)". This shouldn't give results any different from what you've shown using not in though

if you are getting unexpected results, look closer at the SQL and the data as it maybe your expectations that are wrong. What does "select s.id from Report r join r.student where  r.schoolName = :schoolName and r.years = :years" generate to in SQL and does it give you the results you expect? It might be your years clause that is the problem if it isn't

@Chris Code in my question works well. I made changes in         cq.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get("schoolName"), schoolName),                               cb.not(root.get("id").in(subquery))); that where(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("schoolName")).... which solved my problem.

@Chris Thank you for your attention and time
